# Why don't the unitialized indices of a char array print?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

Why doesn't the rest of the `char` array get printed out? Given the following code:

```
char charArray[10];     
charArray[0] = 'a';
charArray[1] = 'b';
charArray[2] = 'c';
charArray[3] = 'd';

string str1 = charArray + string("string") ;
cout << str1;
```

Output: `abcdstring`

While this one:

```
char charArray[10];     
charArray[0] = 'a';
charArray[1] = 'b';
charArray[2] = 'c';

string str1 = charArray + string("string") ;
cout << str1;
```

Output: `abcstring`

I understand that the values in the rest of the array indices are unitialized, but there still are values. So I was expecting random characters to show up there, instead, but I'm not seeing any weird characters which signify uninitialized values.

**So, why doesn't the rest of the `char` array get printed out?** *(Deeper answers with reference to more hardcore stuffs are welcome and greatly appreciated as I'm looking to expand my C++ knowledge to that of an expert.)*

Comment: Because undefined behavior? Chances are the elements of that array are zero initially (by "random luck"), which means it's like a null-terminated string of "abc" or "abcd".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pure luck.

When you use your character array this context

```
string str1 = charArray + string("string")
```

the array is interpreted as a C-style string.

C-style strings are terminated by zero character value. In your case the first uninitialized array element (i.e. `charArray[4]` in the first experiment) just happened to be zero by pure luck (assuming this is a local array). That accidental zero in `charArray[4]` worked as zero-terminator for the string, so your `charArray` happened to stand for a valid C-string `"abcd"`. That's exactly what you see.

The same thing happens in the second experiment.

Comment: When we say zero character value, does that mean the same as null value or uninitialized? If so, how does the program know that the value is uninitialized?

Comment: Zero means 0, i.e. it's as if you did `charArray[4] = 0;`.

Comment: If `charArray` is a static variable rather than a local variable, it's automatically initialized to all zero values.

Comment: @brain56: There's no way to tell an uninitialized object in C from an initialized object. An "uninitialized value" is a regular value that just happens to be unpredictable. In your case that unpredictable value just happened to be `0`. A normal, regular zero just like any other zero.